# Operetta theme on piano/organ roll

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

This beautiful classical overture from opera or operetta has no name. I looked everywhere but can not find this music. If you know the name of this misic, please let me know.

https://www.facebook.com/groups/560220717699143/permalink/971122059942338?sfns=mo

Answer (score 2):

The piece is the overture to the opera "Le maçon" (the Mason) by [Daniel François Esprit Auber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Auber) (1782-1871) a French opera composer and director of the Paris Conservatoire.

[image]

Comment: As a confirmation, here is the same piece played by the 
Czech Philharmonic Chamber Orchestra: https://youtu.be/328xuA1uJto